# Showing the differential of a map $f:S\to\Bbb R^m$ is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I've been asked an exercise where I have to prove that the differential, at a point, of a map defined on surface, is a linear map. I have this definition and then this lemma where they prove this in the first two lines. It's not quite clear to me why that implies it is linear, I am only used to the definition of linearity given by $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ and $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$. Can you expand a little more on that?

> [image]

Comment: The linearity of $(df)_p$ is not "proved in the first two lines". It is a result of the linearity of the two "ordinary" differential maps in the final equality.

Comment: I changed your title and first sentence because they did not make sense, but please tell us if the definition of $(df)_p$ in the exercise you were asked was the same as the definition you found in that book. I am asking this because the notion in the book is a sophisticated one for someone who does not seem used to "ordinary" differentials (i.e. differentials of functions $\Bbb R^p\to\Bbb R^q$).

Comment: @AnneBauval The problem asks me to define the differentiability of $F$ and to show that the differential of $F$ in $p$, $dF_p:T_pS\to R^k$ defined by $dF_p(v)=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}(F \circ \gamma)$ where $\gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to S$ is a smooth curve such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$ is a linear application from $T_pS$ to $R^k$.

Comment: Oh, so you were first asked to define the differentiability of $F$! And what was your answer for that preliminary question? (and btw, what definition of $T_pS$ were you given, if any: was it the same as the "$(TS)_p=(dX)_q(\Bbb R^2)$" above? or was it the same as in the answer below?

Comment: @AnneBauval I used the definition of 2.56.

Answer (score 1):

If $f:S\to\Bbb R^m$ is differentiable at $p\in S$ (a notion you should have defined first, using a convenient parametrization), you said you were told that the differential $df_p:T_pS\to\Bbb R^m$ is defined by
$$df_p(v)=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}(f \circ \alpha)$$
where $\alpha:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to S$ is a differentiable curve such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=v,$ and that you were asked to prove it is linear.

Starting from this definition, the book you are showing us does *not* "prove this in the first two lines". Rather, it is a result of their final equality:
$$(df)_p=d(f\circ X)_q\circ(dX)_q^{-1}.$$
Once this equality is proved (which made them sweat...), the linearity of $(df)_p$ immediately follows from the linearity of the two "ordinary" differential maps $d(f\circ X)_q$ and $(dX)_q.$

Answer (score 0):

**Definition 1**. A tangent vector $V$ at $p\in S$ is an equivalence class of curves $\gamma:[a,b]\to S$ such that $\gamma(a)=p$, where two curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are equivalent if their derivatives at $t=a$ are equal, i.e., $\gamma_1'(a)=\gamma_2'(a)$. Also, it can be defined as an operator from $C^{\infty}(S)$ to $\mathbb R$
$$
V(f)=(f\circ \gamma)'(0)
$$

**Definition 2**. The tangent vector space $T_p S$ is the set of all tangent vectors at $p$. It is a vector space, with the addition and scalar multiplication of tangent vectors **defined pointwise**, and zero vector given by the equivalence class of the constant curve at $p$.

**Definition 3**. The differential of a map $F:S\to \mathbb R^m$ at a point $p\in S$ is a linear map $dF_p:T_p S\to \mathbb R^m$ defined as follows: for any tangent vector $V\in T_p S$, we define $dF_p(V)$ as a vector whose action on a function $g$ in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^m)$ is
$$
dF_p(V)(g)=V(g\circ F)
$$
(observe that $g\circ F \in C^{\infty}(S)$).

With all this three ingredients, you have that $dF_p$ is linear since
$$
dF_p(V+W)(g)=(V+W)(g\circ F)=V(g\circ F)+W(g\circ F)=
$$
$$
=dF_p(V)(g)+dF_p(W)(g)
$$
and
$$
dF_p(\lambda V)(g)=\lambda V(g\circ F)=\lambda dF_p(V)(g)
$$

Comment: Someone downvoted the answer, could you tell me why it's wrong so I can learn from the mistake?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would say that your answer is not appropriate for the level of the OP. The OP is asking in the specific context of the definition he was given for surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$, and you're giving a terse graduate-course level abstract manifolds response.